# UK visit visa enquiries

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Please here is my situation... While in the last semester of my final year in the university in 2012, I applied for a family visit visa to go and spend time with my cousins because I hadn't seen them in a long while. So my uncle (cousin's dad) sent me the invitation while another sponsor (maternal uncle) paid for my flight and gave me pocket money.

I stated that I would spend 6 weeks but stayed for 12 weeks and returned to do my national service.

Now my situation has changed. No more a student. I'm now working and been working full time. I'm planning to go on leave summer this year
This time around, a friend of mine in the same city in UK as my Uncle and cousins is inviting me for holidays.

1.I'm worried that because I stated that I would spend 6weeks and ended up staying for 12weeks during my first visit would create a problem for me.

Please this is my situation at hand. I don't know if I should go ahead with the application or not?

Comment: Since you already have numbers and plans and everything ready, why not just apply for a visa and see if it is approved? Put together the best and most complete application you can -- nothing random people say on the internet should convince you to do anything less; and similarly what could random people on the internet possibly say that would lead you to not even try?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, fair enough, I will delete that comment and replace it with this one: we cannot judge the probabilities of success in visa applications because it requires seeing all your stuff. And per HenningMakholm, random people on the net are unlikely to persuade you either way in the first instance. So in the end, you are asking for an opinion poll for the outcome of a contemplated visa application.  Also see V 4.3.  Close voting as 'opinion-based'.

Answer (score 2):

Comments aside, there are a few of your concrete questions that seem to be answerable, so I'll try:

1. What really matters here is not what you *stated* as your intentions before you went, but what your visa said you were allowed to do.

   If you left the UK before the limit stated in your visa and/or the entry stamp in your passport, then you didn't do anything wrong, and changing your plans within the limits given to you by the authorities themselves shouldn't count against you.

   If, on the other hand, you *overstayed* the time limit, you have a problem. The UK government may not currently *know* you overstayed, since they didn't have exit checks in place in 2012 -- but the visa application will require you to provide details of your earlier visit, and if you lie there and are later found out, you will end up in considerably worse trouble than the overstay itself would have caused.
2. As you describe it, it doesn't sound like something that should be a showstopper. Your application should include information and documentation of your uncle's financial situation that will allow the consular officer to conclude it is reasonable for him to gift you (part of) a holiday trip.

   Be sure not to describe this uncle as a "sponsor"; that has a particular meaning in the visa context and could be confusing.
3. If you truthfully state that you're not going to meet them, you don't need to "justify" that they're not there to meet. The visa application will still ask about any relatives you have in the UK -- uncles and cousins do *not* count as relatives for this purpose, but you should explain *anyway* that they're there, who they are, and that it's not them you're going to see. *Not* mentioning them will make it look like you're hiding something, particularly since you had a family visit visa earlier. But it's not as if just because they're there you'll never be allowed to go to the UK except to visit them.
4. No idea.
5. No idea. It sounds like plenty for two weeks if you'll be living with your friend and it's exclusive of the flights to/from the UK. But what do I know?

Comment: I didn't over stay my visa though.

Comment: Yes I intend to mention my uncle and cousins. But then again I am asked if I would visit or stay with them. Yes or No? That's where the confusion comes. They live in the same city as my friend inviting me.

Comment: 'Be sure not to describe this uncle as a "sponsor"; that has a particular meaning in the visa context and could be confusing.'- please could you elaborate what you meant by this? I don't really understand.  My sponsor is only supporting with flight ticket. I mentioned two uncles in my situation. (My relative abroad and my maternal uncle here in my home country).

Comment: @Brigit: Just answer truthfully. If you're not going to stay with the uncle and cousins, answer no when the application form asks you whether you're staying with them. If you _are_ going to stay with them, answer yes. I don't see what is confusing about that.

Comment: @Brigit: Do not use the word "sponsor" about the uncle who is paying for your ticket. If you call him "sponsor", there's a risk that the ECO will think you mean he's a "sponsor" in the visa sense -- that is, someone living in the UK who provides a declaration that helps convince the ECO that you should get a visa (for example, by guaranteeing that you will have a place to stay without needing to pay a hotel). Since that makes no sense, the ECO could get the impression that you're just making things up. Just don't use the word "sponsor".

Comment: Oh OK. Great. Got the 'sponsor' bit clearly. Thank you. @Henning Makholm